# Java round double and get a double

Tags: java, precision, rounding

I have seen numerous examples of rounding using DecimalFormat and NumberFormat but these return Strings when used.  Yes I know that one can use parse to get the number back, however this adds complexity.

So how does one round a double to a given precision and get a double back with as few midsteps as possible?

Comment: You can only round a `double` to a precision in base 2, not to a precision in terms of "number of decimal points."  If you want to work with a number of decimal points, you really, really, really should be using `BigDecimal`.

Comment: Is there any way to write it so that it is in base 10?

Comment: Sure, use `BigDecimal`.  Other than that, no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no real way to do that. You could do the old (X*10^N)/10^N trick, I suppose, but you may not get the arbitrary precision you want. That's the trick with floating point numbers. If you want arbitrary precision, you need to use BigDecimal.